# Dot product cancellation

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, products

Given vectors $a,b,c$, I know that
$$
c\cdot a=c\cdot b
$$
does not imply $a=b$ (take three orthogonal vectors, for example).

However, if I say that $c\cdot a=c\cdot b$ holds for any vector $c$, is it then true that $a=b$? How should I argue?

Comment: Since $c\cdot(a-b)=0$ for all $c$, take $c=a-b$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:
$$c\cdot a=c\cdot b\implies c\cdot a-c\cdot b=0$$
$$\implies c\cdot(a-b)=0$$

What do we infer  if this equation holds for every $c$?

Comment: Perfect, thanks!

Comment: @samwolfe You're welcome!!!!

Answer (score 5):

Hint:

If the equation holds for every $c$, you can put $c=a-b$.

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$c\cdot a=c\cdot b \iff c\cdot (a-b)=0 \iff c=0 \quad \lor \quad a-b=0 \quad \lor \quad c\perp (a-b)$$

and since $c$ can assume any value only  the case $a-b=0$ remains therefore

$$\forall c\,,\quad c\cdot a=c\cdot b \iff a=b $$

Comment: @ThomasShelby The dot product of two vectors is equal to zero only if one is equal to zero or if they are perpendicular. Since c can be any vector only $a=b$ remains. Isn't it clear?

Comment: I guess one could go to the extreme of saying that, since we're assuming $c$ is any vector, imposing conditions such as $c=0$ or $c\perp (a-b)$ would go against such assumption. Thus $a-b=0$ remains as the only possibility, as you said. Very clear answer, thank you!

Comment: @samwolfe Yes exactly! Maybe not the most brilliant but it works fine I think! Thanks, Bye